# how to pretrain my image using resnet50 in mask-rcnn

Tags: machine-learning, resnet

I am researching about mask r-cnn. I want to know how to pretrain my image(knife,sofa,baby,.....) using resnet50 in mask-rcnn. I struggle to find that in github, but I can't. Please help me anybody who know how to handle it.

Comment: What do you mean by pretrain your image? That's not a common term.

Comment: Resnet 50 offer pre trained image to me. I think that it's provide for object detecting in mask r cnn. Coco dataset images(full image) were used in mask r cnn to detect object. So I want to pretraining my image(eg knife, sofa,baby,...) in resnet50 instead of pretrained images. Resnet50's pretrining output is cpkg file. So how can I get pretrained image in resnet by my image???

Answer (score -1):

Try this implementation of Mask RCNN on github [here](https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN).

Answer (score -1):

You can follow [Mask_RCNN](https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN) github repo. It has both resnet50 and resnet100 (might be wrong here). It is a beautiful implementation I would say. The base model is from FAIR (Facebook AI Research). There is a demo file which you can check before starting your work.

If it works well, you can see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49684468/mask-r-cnn-for-object-detection-and-segmentation-train-for-a-custom-dataset/50226115#50226115), it will help you to train the model with your custom data. The answer is a bit long, but it lists all the steps.

Something which I personally like about this implementation is:

- It is easy to setup. Won't bother you much about the dependencies. Having a python virtual environment does the wonders.
- It falls back automatically from a CPU version to GPU and vice versa.
- It is having good support from its developers. It is getting commits frequently.
- The code is very customisable. So If you want to do some changes, it's pretty easy. Some booleans and numbers changes up and down and you are done...!!!